# How do I get the class names hot swapped by IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hotswap

We have a pretty large java codebase.

We use IntelliJ IDEA to remotely connect to our JVM and then use hot swap to apply code changes to the JVM.

How do I make IDEA show me the names of the files/classes that it hot swapped? Right now, it just shows a message like

```
"..Swapped 4 classes.."
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not guaranteed to work in all situations (notably, method signature changes)...figured I'd let you know.